# PHP $_SESSION empties after a try{}catch(){} block

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-state

after I finally found a Paypal IPN scripts that works great, I have a problem with `$_SESSION` emptying after a `try{} catch(){}` block.

The thing is the IPN is `VERIFIED`, I am 100% sure about this. In fact I get errors(logged to a file) from inside the `if()` block which if after the `try{} catch(){}` block.

This is the code

```
 include($_SERVER['WROOT'].'core/init.php');

$total = 0;
$prodArray = array();
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $prodID => $prodInfo) {
    $product = getProduct($prodID, $dbh);
    $currQty = 0; $itemTotal = 0;
    foreach($prodInfo as $size => $qta) { $currQty += $qta; }
    $itemTotal = ($product->sale_price != 0) ? $currQty * $product->sale_price : $currQty * $product->price;
    $total += $itemTotal;
    array_push($prodArray, $prodID);
}
$total = number_format($total, 2, '.', ',');

/*
PayPal IPN with PHP
How To Implement an Instant Payment Notification listener script in PHP
http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html
(c) 2011 - Micah Carrick
*/

// tell PHP to log errors to ipn_errors.log in this directory
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', 'logs/ipn_errors.log');

DEFINE('DEVELOPER_EMAIL', 'dev@email.com');
DEFINE('MERCHANT_EMAIL', 'merchant@email.com');
DEFINE('MC_GROSS', $total);
DEFINE('MC_CURRENCY', 'EUR');

// intantiate the IPN listener
include('core/classes/IpnListenerClass.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();

// tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
$listener->use_sandbox = true;

// try to process the IPN POST
try {
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit(0);
}

if ( $verified ) {

    $errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks

    // 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed" 
    if ( $_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed' ) { 
        // simply ignore any IPN that is not completed
        exit(0); 
    }
     // 2. Make sure seller email matches your primary account email.
    if ( $_POST['receiver_email'] != MERCHANT_EMAIL ) {
        $errmsg .= "'receiver_email' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['receiver_email']."\n";
    }

    // 3. Make sure the amount(s) paid match
    if ( $_POST['mc_gross'] != $total ) {
        $errmsg .= "'mc_gross' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= "$total\n";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_gross']."\n";
    }

    // 4. Make sure the currency code matches
    if ( $_POST['mc_currency'] != MC_CURRENCY ) {
        $errmsg .= "'mc_currency' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_currency']."\n";
    }

    // 5. Ensure the transaction is not a duplicate.
    $checkTxn = $dbh->prepare(" SELECT txn_id FROM orders WHERE txn_id = :txn_id ");
    $checkTxn->execute(array( 'txn_id' => Input::post('txn_id') ));
    if ( $checkTxn->rowCount() == 1 ) {
        $errmsg .= "'txn_id' already processed: ";
    }

    if (!empty($errmsg)) {

        // manually investigate errors from the fraud checking
        $body = "IPN failed fraud checks: \n$errmsg\n\n";
        $body .= $listener->getTextReport();
        mail(DEVELOPER_EMAIL, 'Walking Outlet IPN Fraud Warning', $body);

    } else {
        // add this order to a table of completed orders
        $orderDetails = array(
            'txn_status'    => Input::post('payment_status'),
            'txn_id'        => Input::post('txn_id'),
            'user'          => Session::getUser(),
            'comments'      => (!Input::emptyPost('memo')) ? Input::post('memo') : ''
        );
        $newOrder = $dbh->prepare("
            INSERT INTO 
                orders(txn_status, txn_id, user, order_date, comments) 
                VALUES(:txn_status, :txn_id, :user, NOW(), :comments)
        ");
        $newOrder->execute($orderDetails);
        $orderID = $dbh->lastInsertId('id');

        // add the ordered items to the table
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $prodID => $prodInfo) {
            $product = getProduct($prodID, $dbh);
            foreach($prodInfo as $size => $qta) {
                $itemDetails = array(
                    'order_id'  => $orderID,
                    'item_id'   => $prodID,
                    'item_size' => $size,
                    'item_qta'  => $qta
                );
                $newItem = $dbh->prepare("
                    INSERT INTO
                        order_items(order_id, item_id, item_size, item_qta) 
                        VALUES(:order_id, :item_id, :item_size, :item_qta)
                ");
                $newItem->execute($itemDetails);
            }
        }

        // send seller an email with buyer information
        $to = filter_var(DEVELOPER_EMAIL, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $subject = "Nuovo ordine effettuato";
        $message = print_r($_SESSION);
        mail($to, $subject, $message);

    }

} else {
    // manually investigate the invalid IPN
    mail(DEVELOPER_EMAIL, 'Walking Outlet - Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
}
```

Any suggestions on what it could be ? The `exit(0)` code does not execute because if it would, I would not get the errors from inside the `if()` block.

EDIT: So I posted my whole code.

Comment: IPN script is hit by automated paypal bot, you shouldn't use session variables in it.

Comment: How do you know `$_SESSION` is empty? You don't reference it after the try/catch blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the code because is quite big. I will update the code.

Comment: @Dagon The problem is that I have to check the logged user and the products in the shopping cart to be able to check if the mt_gross from PayPal is correct and to insert the products in the database after the payment has been made, all this through $_SESSION. What do you suggest ?

Comment: If you are 100% sure it happens inside the `try-catch` blocks then you should focus on what `$listener` does. Nothing else should matter.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I think that's the problem, but if it really is that, then the code should stop at that point and I would not have any mails sent to me from inside the if() blocks, also the logs would be empty.

Comment: the paypal bot hitting the script has no idea about your users sessions!

Comment: @Dagon I just found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755244/paypal-ipn-having-trouble-accessing-session-data So you are right. Seems that I have to store my products in the database to perform the checks afterwards.